# How to get a list of all songs in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

Is there an easy way to get a list of all my songs in iTunes into a text file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually insanely simple:

Open iTunes and go into your music library. Click on a song to ensure focus is inside the song list, press <kbd>⌘a</kbd> to select all your songs, then press <kbd>⌘c</kbd> to copy them.

Open the text editor of your choice, anything should do, then <kbd>⌘v</kbd> paste your songs!

Ét Voíla, all your songs listed in plain text.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was probably going to have to use Apple Script or something

Comment: You could also unshow comments to get just the details you want

Comment: By comments, you meant "columns", I assume?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: That's a really really good point. Visible columns copied, so arrange the columns as you want to see them in text representation. Nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a nice pdf with the content of your music library: hit `⌘P` to open the print dialog, select "Album list" (I'm using a not english version of iTunes, son I'm not fully sure of the label, I mean the third radiobox from the top) and the "Only text" theme (the first option on the select field). Click "Print..." and then Save as PDF.

The resulting document is really nice:
[image]

Comment: For reference, in English, Davide is saying to go into your library, hit ⌘p, choose 'Album Listing' (the last radio button option), the theme name will change to 'Songs by album', leave that if you prefer the look of the above screenshot. Then use the PDF button on the bottom left to save as a PDF, or of course you can print it normally. It will look like the above, which is very slick.

Comment: Thanks for completing my answer with the proper English reference!

Answer (score 1):

You already have one - albeit an XML file. Default place is ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml